# Why doesn't my default layout get rendered to my github page?

Tags: html, layout, github, yaml, jekyll

i'm entirely new to github pages and jekyll and yaml and i've run into some problems while creating my very first project. I suspect the problem lies with the _config file but I have no idea what it is. If you take a look at my site [mohmanyang.com](http://mohmanyang.com), you see that the yaml is rendered as text instead of being replaced with code from the "default.html" which can be found in the _layouts folder. Here is the project on github, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you're developing on Windows and that your editor is saving files with `utf-8 with BOM`.

Jekyll doesn't like `BOM`. Saving you files with `utf-8` with no BOM will make the magic.

Comment: Hi @DavidJacquel thanks for pointing this out. I'll give it a try